# Как работать с базой данных во flask

Tags: python, база-данных, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Изучаю базы данных во flask по этой статье. https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/
Там приведён такой код

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

Но я не понимаю что значит эта строчка

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
```

Где создается база данных?

Comment: В каталоге /tmp создаётся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

База SQLite создастся локально, в `/tmp/test.db`
В начале строки, в `sqlite://` – объявляется протокол/тип подключения.